# AxiosError: Request failed with status code 407

Tags: javascript, axios, proxy

We are trying to use axios for making calls to an API. Was getting blocked by proxy error HTTP status code 407, and 400 for whatever we try to fix it.

AxiosError: Request failed with status code 407
at settle (/xxx/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:1268:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/xxx/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2446:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:549:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Apparently, axios is not happy with the environment variables defined for proxy.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various things, landed upon this [post](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2072#issuecomment-567473812)! This resolved our issue!! The only extra thing I needed was to add the proxy username and password:

`new HttpsProxyAgent('http://username:password@proxy-host:8000');`

```
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

const const axiosDefaultConfig = {
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    proxy: false,
    httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://proxy-host:8000') };

const axios = require ('axios').create(axiosDefaultConfig); axios.get('42')
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Response with axios was ok: ' + response.status);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```